# Running jQuery scripts on DOM elements loaded with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I understand that jQuery will not run when the DOM content is being loaded via AJAX. But I'm confused as to the reason why. My understanding was that the DOM elements didn't exist at the time the jQuery was initiated therefore it won't find the correct IDs or classes.

But I have a situation where the jQuery is only called AFTER all the content has been loaded via AJAX. yet it still does not work.

Here is my code. I am trying to get the function `decorateGains()` to run after AJAX completes.

```
loadData('7-days'); // Runs the default AJAX for 7 days
function loadData(type){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}
    else{xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){document.getElementById("home-table").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;}
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","actions/get-data-"+type+".php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    decorateGains();
}
```

You can see that I am including a call to the function `decorateGains()` right at the end of the `loadData()` function.

The `decorateGains()` function *does* run, as I can see my console message. However it does not do the task that it should.

```
function decorateGains() {
    console.log('here');
    $(".gains").each(function() { 
        var num = +($(this).text());
        if (num > 0) {
            console.log('here');
            $(this).addClass("positive");
        }
        if (num < 0) {
            console.log('here');
            $(this).addClass("negative");
        }
    });
}
```

(The script searches for all elements with a class of `.gains` and adds a new class of `positive` or `negative` depending on the content of the element. Essentially it decorates the `.gains` element to be red or green depending on whether the number is negative or positive).

Comment: Your problem is that, that the ajax is asunchron. So, `DecorateGains();` run befor the response arrives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the AJAX call is asynchronous. The request has not been completed (and therefore the new content has not been appended to the DOM) when you call your `decorateGains()` function. You need to place the call to the function inside the `onreadystatechange` handler, after setting the `innerHTML`:

```js
loadData('7-days'); // Runs the default AJAX for 7 days
function loadData(type) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("home-table").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

            decorateGains(); // <-- move this in here
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "actions/get-data-" + type + ".php", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a great explanation and thanks for the code example. I knew it was something along these lines :)

Comment: @Francesca no problem at all, glad to help.